# Sketch a set in the complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers

How to sketch this set in the complex plane?
$$S=\{ z\in C: Re[(4-i)z] > Re[(-5+7i)(4+6i)] \}$$
Where:

- S - set
- Re[x+yi] - real part of the complex number
- C - complex    numbers
- z - complex number

---

I solved the Real parts inside the brackets and here what I`ve got:
$$Re[(4-i)z] = Re[(4-i)(x+iy)] = Re[(4x+y) + i(4y-x)] = 4x+y$$
$$Re[(-5+7i)(4+6i)] = Re[-20-30i+28i-42] = Re[-64-2i] = -64$$
After that I have an inequality:
$$4x+y>-64$$

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Can you invent and solve a similar problem with simpler complex numbers?

Comment: @EthanBolker I have added everything I did to the post

Comment: You've done most of the work. Finding out where those points are in the plane is just old fashioned analytic geometry - nothing to do with complex numbers. Start with where that inequality is an equality.

Comment: @EthanBolker At first I`ve got tricked a bit but then yes I tried and everything looks fine! Thank you.

Comment: Please try not to use irrelevant tags. If you’re not sure, check their meanings.

Comment: @TedShifrin okay okay, I will be careful next time!

Comment: "After that I have an inequality:
4x+y>−64"  Do you know how to graph that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: wolfram alpha plot]

So this is how it looks like plotted by Wolfram Alpha (it goes through x=-16)